# Java - Pattern matching between the same pattern

Tags: java, regex

My sample string:

```
 a ghgduysgd a fdferfdf a bvfxbgdf a gdfgdfg
```

I need to find all the contents between a's.

I have `(?<=a).*` But it matches all the contents after a. But I want to find between a.

First iteration: `ghgduysgd`

Second iteration: `fdferfdf`

I want to get data like the above for the manipulation. can you help with regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You alrady use a lookbehind in your regex, change it to also use a lookahead:

```
(?<=a).*(?=a|$)
```

Then make the `.*` non-greedy to stop at the first available "ending" `a`:

```
(?<=a).*?(?=a|$)
```

EDIT: the `a|$` is from tobias_k's comment below, originally it was just `a`

Comment: It matches only first two strings

Comment: Guess you could change the lookahead to `a|$` to fix that.

Comment: @GopsAB It should match the third one as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can try regex like this (and ignore the first value)

```
String path = "a ghgduysgd a fdferfdf a bvfxbgdf a gdfgdfg";
String[] arr = path.split("(\\s+)?a(\\s+|$)"); // split based on a preceeded and followed by space
for (String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P :

```
// Empty String here. Since your String starts with a
ghgduysgd
fdferfdf
bvfxbgdf
gdfgdfg
```

Comment: @GopsAB - Yes. You could try

Answer (score 1):

You could split the String where there is an "a" and then trim the spaces and save it in an ArrayList. Then if you want to print the whole word you could use Stringbuilder to concatenate the Strings.

```
   String word="a ghgduysgd a fdferfdf a bvfxbgdf a gdfgdfg";
        List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        list= Arrays.asList(word.split("a")); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String item: list){
            item.trim();
        System.out.println(item);
        sb.append(item);
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Thought the same. But ended up with regex.